# PyQt5: Why self.sender() returns the base object not the derived one sent it

Tags: pyqt5, qobject, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am writing a server/client code with PyQt5 sockets and I met a strange behavior
First, I derived a class from QTCPSocket, so that I abstract the usage of socket to my data frame, use encryption,..etc before sending the data
So, let this class = mySocket which is an inherited class from QTCPSocket

mySocket has some variables in its **init**, Ex: self.key. And as I do in all sockets, I connected its readyread signal to my slot of name: ***rxdata***

Now, the problem.
inside ***rxdata***, when I try to get the sender object ( using self.sender() ), what it returns is object of type QTCPSocket not as I was expecting a mySocket object. Which I don't understand

I tried to cast the QTCPsocket returned using qtcpsocketObj.**class** =mySocket 
but the problem now, is mySocket.**init()** obviously not called, this the variables like self.key won't be defined.

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Works fine for me using pyqt 5.13.0. What ***specific*** version of pyqt are you testing with?

Comment: what do u mean by fine? sender returns the derived class + u can access its variables (defined in __init__() )from the returned object ?

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Yes - it sends the right class and user-defined attributes are accessible. And I repeat: what ***specific*** version of pyqt5 are you testing with?

Comment: How to know ? I only piped instll pyqt5

Comment: my version is 5.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and debugging,

the problem wasn't from self.sender(). the problem was that the QTCPServer object returns QTCPSocket, and casting it using _ *class* _() as I did wasn't the right way.

The solution was to derive a class from QTCPServer and instead of making it return QTCPSocket, it will return mySocket class object ( the details is well explained in documentation)
Here is a sample code:

```
class myQTCPServer(QTcpServer):
     def __init__(self,parent=None):
         super(myQTCPServer, self).__init__(parent)

def incomingConnection(self,socketDescriptor):
        newSock = mySocket(self) 
        newSock.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)
        self.addPendingConnection(newSock)
```